# Insert overwrite Hive Table via the databricks notebook is throwing error

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I've batch job that inserts the data to hive table on a daily basis and creates multiple smaller ORC's files on the blob location, i will need to combine all the small ORC files to one larger ORC file so that the read performance would be much better.

In this context, i used to schedule the below SQL query to run every day post my batch job completes in Azure HDInsight. When i try to schedule the same query in Azure Databricks notebook, it's throwing the below error. Is there a reason why this works in HDInsight and not working in Azure Databricks notebook.
Is there a better way i can achieve this.

My Azure Databricks runtime version: 6.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY dlloaddate desc;
```

Error:

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DDLUtils$.verifyNotReadPath(ddl.scala:962)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceAnalysis.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:109)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:101)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$analyzed$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$analyzed$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:716)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:88)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLDriverLocal.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:34)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:141)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:126)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:141)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION partition_spec] CONCATENATE
```

can be used to merge small ORC files into a larger file, starting in Hive 0.14.0. The merge happens at the stripe level, which avoids decompressing and decoding the data.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC

Comment: Hello @srikanth, we cannot issue ALTER TABLE command from Azure Databricks notebook, Getting the error: Operation not allowed: ALTER TABLE CONCATENATE(line 1, pos 0)